# how to create multi dimension LIsts in dart Language?

Tags: dart

How to create Multidimensional List in dart?.  IN other languages we can use array for this But in dart
we use List . SO i find in google I could not found method for Create Multidimensional List in dart ? 
Anyone Know create Multidimensional List in dart ?

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to accomplish that. The simplest solution is to create a list of lists like:

```
void main() {
  // Create 5x5 list
  List<List<int>> twoDimList = List.generate(5, (_) => List.filled(5, 0));
  twoDimList[0][0] = 5;
  print(twoDimList);
}
```

A more efficient way to do it is to use a single list and access it by using two coordinates like the following class I have used in a previous project:

```
class Grid<T> {
  final int length, height;
  final List<T> list;

  Grid(this.length, this.height) : list = List(length * height);

  T get(int x, int y) => list[_getPos(x, y)];
  void set(int x, int y, T value) => list[_getPos(x, y)] = value;

  int _getPos(int x, int y) => x + (y * length);
}
```